# ShopifyAPI get product variant from inventory_item_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm having trouble using ShopifyAPI to get a variant from an inventory_item_id. Here's a sample response from `ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:all)`:

```
{"id"=>40232259485873, "title"=>"red", "price"=>"10.00", "sku"=>"1", "position"=>1, "inventory_policy"=>"deny", "compare_at_price"=>nil, "fulfillment_service"=>"manual", "inventory_management"=>"shopify", "option1"=>"red", "option2"=>nil, "option3"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2021-06-26T15:22:08-04:00", "updated_at"=>"2021-07-14T22:49:15-04:00", "taxable"=>true, "barcode"=>"", "grams"=>0, "image_id"=>nil, "weight"=>0.0, "weight_unit"=>"kg", "inventory_item_id"=>42322551111851, "inventory_quantity"=>8, "requires_shipping"=>true, "admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/41111111111111"}
```

As you can see, the `inventory_item_id` is `42322551111851`. But when I do this: `product_variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:all, :params=> {:inventory_item_id => 42322551111851).first`, I get the wrong variant which doesn't match with the `inventory_item_id` that I specified. I'm using API version 2021-04. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is considered to be the scope of the query. That is, how many resources are returned from the request. It can be one of the following.

:one  - Returns a single resource.
:first  - Returns the first resource found.
:last  - Returns the last resource found.
:all  - Returns every resource that matches the request.

whats your idea about this code:

```
::ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:first, :params=> {inventory_item_id: '42322551111851'})
```

more details:

```
https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/product-variant#resource-object
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).